# MS Word – how to insert a column on the right edge of each page

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting

I am writing some test questions in Microsoft Word. 
I want to add a grey column on the right, that text should not cross,
as indicated by the (hand-drawn) yellow column below.

[image: current output]

How can this be achieved?

The following is an image of what I want.

[image: desired output]

(Obviously, I don't have access to the above document; just its image.)

A copy of the first file (with the math questions, but without the column)
can be viewed at and downloaded from [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7w4jfju8mks2m4b/sample.docx?dl=0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Set the right margin to where you want it.
- Click on the “Insert” tab.
- In the “Header & Footer” panel, click on “Header” → “Edit Header”.
- Click on the “Insert” tab again.
- In the “Illustrations” panel, click on “Shapes” and select the rectangle.
- Insert a rectangle
  that stretches from the top margin to the bottom margin,
  to the right of the right margin.
- You should now be on the “Format” tab.
- In the “Shape Styles” panel, click on “Shape Fill”
  and select the color you want.
- Double-click on “Header” to return to the document.

... or you can do the same thing, but use the footer.

Comment: Worked beautifully. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same thing by creating a table and formatting the far-right column with the shading and border line you want.